# Update People field using REST and javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, user-profile

I have webpage that uses a client side people picker and allows the user to address a message to other valid users within our on-prem SharePoint 2013.

I'm trying to write a record of the message to a list and having problems with the **Recipients** part of the list item. Recipients is a multipick people column.

I've found many tutorials [like this one](http://sharepoint.sureshc.com/2016/05/how-to-update-person-field-with-multiple-values-using-rest-api.html) which show that **Recipients** will get another hidden field called **RecipientsId** and that I can use a REST call like

```
data: { "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.ListNameListItem" },
        "Title": "The title",
         "RecipientsId": ["5","7"] };
```

But there are a couple of reasons the `<name>Id` column won't work. First The user Id number is based upon if the user has visited my site (or maybe site collection?) In any event a user who visits my site might send to a recipient who has never been to my site and therefore doesn't have a local user id.

The other problem is that I'm following this [on how to use the client people picker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593.aspx) and it shows how to get the details about the people in the picker with this code:

```
var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;
var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
```

But the information returned about the users in the people picker doesn't include the Id. I assume this is also because of issue #1 where the user in the people picker may not have an Id on the current site. Here is the information that is returned.

```
AutoFillDisplayText:"First Last"
AutoFillKey:"i:0#.w|domain\IdNumber"
AutoFillSubDisplayText:"Job Title"
AutoFillTitleText:"First.Last@example.com↵Active Directory↵domain\IdNumber"
Description:"domain\IdNumber
DisplayText:"First Last"
DomainText:"collectionurl"
EntityData:Object
EntityType:"User"
IsResolved:true
Key:"i:0#.w|domain\IdNumber"
LocalSearchTerm:"first last"
MultipleMatches:Array[0]
ProviderDisplayName:"Active Directory"
ProviderName:"AD"
Resolved:true
```

What I would like to do is user the `Key` or `AutoFillKey` or `Description` to populate the Recipients Column. I have tried those and also tried stripping out the leading `i:0#.w` and/or domain with no success.

**TL;DR**

Is there a way to directly write to a person column (and not the hidden related Id) using the REST api?

If there isn't...

How do I get the UserId for a user based on the info available in a people picker?

How to I get a UserId for someone who has never been to my site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In any event a user who visits my site might send to a recipient who
>   has never been to my site and therefore doesn't have a local user id.

It looks like you are able to post people to the list so long as they are present on the site. You might try using the `ensureUser` method first.

**From Microsoft:**

> EnsureUser method Checks whether the specified login name belongs to a
>   valid user in the site. If the user doesn't exist, adds the user to
>   the site.
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>   url: "http://<site url>/_api/web/ensureuser",
>   type: "POST",
>   data: "{ 'logonName': 'i:0#.f|membership|user@domain.onmicrosoft.com' }",
>   headers: {
>     "X-RequestDigest": <form digest value>,
>     "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
>   },
>   success: successHandler,
>   error: errorHandler
> });
> ```
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819.aspx#bk_WebEnsureUser

**Example with REST by [Vadim Gremyachev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1375553/vadim-gremyachev):**

> ```
> function ensureUser(webUrl,loginName)
> {
>    var payload = { 'logonName': loginName }; 
>    return $.ajax({
>       url: webUrl + "/_api/web/ensureuser",
>       type: "POST",
>       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
>       data: JSON.stringify(payload),
>       headers: {
>          "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
>          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
>       }
>    });  
> }
>
>
> var loginName = 'i:0#.f|membership|jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com'
> ensureUser(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,loginName)
> .done(function(data)
> {
>     console.log('User has been added');
> })
> .fail(function(error){
>     console.log('An error occured while adding user');
> });
> ```
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259576/sharepoint-2013-ensureuser-via-rest-api

**Example with CSOM by [Steve_Butler](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/steve_butler/?ws=usercard-mini):**

> ```
> function EnsureUser(LoginName) {
>     appWebContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
>     var theUser = appWebContext.get_web().ensureUser(LoginName);
>     results = appWebContext.load(theUser);
>     appWebContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(null, ensureUserSuccess), Function.createDelegate(null, ensureUserFailure));
> }
> ```
>
> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c6630cb5-7508-4193-8917-6ea16cb43309/js-and-rest-posting-to-a-persongroup-field-in-a-list?forum=sharepointdevelopment

**UPDATE:**

If you have your array of recipients you could add the Deferred of each into an array and iterate over the results.

```
function ensureArrayOfUsers(arrayOfUserIds){
    var arrayOfPromises = [];
    arrayOfUserIds.map(function(userId){
        arrayOfPromises.push(ensureUser(webUrl, user));
    });
    return $.when.apply($, arrayOfPromises);
}

ensureArrayOfUsers(arrayOfUserIds)
.done(function(){
    // write to list
});
```

Comment: So I'm taking it that there isn't a way to actually add users directly, but only with the ID? With the ensureuser is there a way to batch that, since there might be more than one recipient? I'm using jquery for my REST calls, if I can't batch them do you know how I would make sure that I've ensured all users before I proceed?

Comment: I updated my answer. Note I did not test the code.

Comment: I will give that a try. Thank you. It is a bummer that the people picker doesn't return the information needed to actually use the people picker for any kind of usual purpose, huh?

Comment: That works great. I've never really understood "$.when()" nor .apply() I will have to reread the documentation. Even though I can't add a user directly this makes it not too hard to do. Thank you very much.